# My JavaScript code won't run after jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

jQuery code in a script1.js file

```
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $.ajax({
       method:"GET",
       url:"someurl",
       success : 
       (data,status,xhr)=>{
         //Create some html buttons after I get the data

         //I want to append the js file here(the JavaScript file adds some event functions to the newly created buttons.I know i can add the event listeners to the button directly here but for some reason I prefer to have the code in a separate js file) 
        //This does not work
          $('head'). append('<script src="script_here"></script>')

        }
     })
})
```

JavaScript code in a script2.js file

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',ready)

function ready (){
   document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',()=>{
   //Do some other stuff
  })
}
```

I have tried  appending the script2.js file through the jQuery but its not working.

I do not want to have everything in one file for easy debugging, and I need to have both vanilla js and jQuery in my project.

Comment: Most likely the DOMContentLoaded event is not happening after the point that your second script is adding the event handler for it to the document.

Comment: The load event too won't work..am also getting a warning in my browser (Synchronous  xmlhttprequest jQuery.js  on main thread is deprecated because of detrimental effects to end user experience )  When i have the script without the DOMContentLoaded and Load events

Comment: So back up a second.  Why do you think you need an event handler for that logic, rather than just running the logic?

Comment: In the script2.js you mean?

Comment: Yep, why do you need that?

Comment: I have some other pages relying on the same script2.js file..I believe its good practice to load the script after DOM is ready..

Comment: Right, but look at this use case.  You perform logic in a document ready, which will wait for the DOM to be loaded (pretty much the same thing as the DOMContentLoaded event).  You then perform an ajax request.  **Then** once the ajax request has finished, you then append the script to pull script2 in.  Completely ignoring that you are already inside a document ready, the likely hood that an ajax request would finish before your DOM is loaded is very very small.

Comment: Understood from your point of view.but removing it will cause the other pages relying on the same script to 'misbehave'.I wouldn't want scripts running on pages that have not loaded

Comment: Then you are coding yourself into a stuck place.  Because the load event and the DOMContentLoaded events only fire once.  If you make an event binding for them after they have fired, that logic will never execute.

Comment: Understoood.I have tried removing the DOM events but I am getting some errors i.e  redeclaration of varibles but I cant see any after debugging

Comment: On your site is there ever a case where script2 is included on a page that does not also include jQuery?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215122/discussion-between-eric-nderitu-and-taplar).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load an external js file after the ajax call. Then I will show you using in Pure JS. As I have encountered similar issue, so it might help you.

```
(data,status,xhr)=>{
    const fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    fileref.setAttribute('src',
    'https://speechanywhere.nuancehdp.com/3.0/scripts/Nuance.SpeechAnywhere.js?_r=' +
    (Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 18)).toString(32)); // the math random will help from cache errors each time you load
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);
}
```

[Import and use external JS Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58463290/9739044)

Comment: `document.head` is already accessable.  Same as `document.body`